# Is it a valid strategy at workplace to select the people you work and comunicate with and avoid the rest?

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, colleagues, ethics, conflict

I am closing on my 20 years working as IT. I am above average skilled and loud enough to be able to gain focus, raise through the ranks and then fall. Have done it several times :) I have had occasions when people really want to work with me and people who try to avoid me. I have personaly never ever tried to avoid anyone. But as I am nearing my forties, I have started to question myself about all the friction you get being loud and interacting with as many as possible people.

Is it a viable strategy to interact only with people you like to interact and to avoid those you prefer to not? Can a person perform it in a professional way? Can I avoid all the meetings that draw me near people I prefer to not interact with?

UPDATE: Mostly I am interested in what are the pitfalls of such a strategy. What can I gain, what can I lose?

Comment: Depends on the goal. What is yours?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser if I only knew. I know I am a bit tired of fighting and people activly sabotaging me. So I am considering of just walling them, but am a little bit afraid if this will fire back. I have not done that before in my life , but I have observed many doing it,

Comment: @MatthewGaiser mostly what I am interested in are what are the pitfalls of such strategy.

Comment: It is an effective way to work around your limitations, but in the end you will still be seen as the developer with limitations.

Comment: @Pesho, you should first try to understand why you're not getting along with the others and see what can be done. Trying to insulate yourself will mark you as a difficult person. That might be OK for a while, but it will eventually harm your career if you want to advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are, as you suspect, some benefits and some drawbacks to this strategy.

Benefits include less time spent in arguing, unwanted small talks, and other unpleasant social interactions.  You may have more time to focus and work if you have a lesser number of people accustomed to working or socializing with you regularly.  If the ones you block out are a reasonably small group of people you don't actually need to work closely with in order to perform your job functions, and with whom you share no required meetings, this can work out fine.  Many coworkers may not even be aware that you're intentionally ignoring people.  It's normal to have some work friends or favored people for social interactions, and some you rarely speak to.  As long as you aren't openly hostile to your out-group, accept the most basic ask-about-your-weekend type interactions if they are offered, and don't go around doing anything as silly as telling others who you've decided to avoid, this can be perfectly professional.

This decision can have some pretty big drawbacks, however, especially if people find out that you're intentionally separating your coworkers into 'ok' and 'do not engage' groups.  On the obvious side, this includes getting a reputation for being odd, rude, unfriendly, or "hard to work with" yourself.  You may miss out on important information if you're not on speaking terms with the people who know it.  You may not be selected for new projects, or even promotions, if you are perceived as having a difficult time with the social aspects of the workplace.  You may give people the idea that you're not a Team Player if you aren't willing to pitch in on things or join projects if certain people are working on them. You may lose the chance to learn from other smart people, or to form connections that are advantageous either for your career or personally.

You probably can't skip out on group meetings that include one or more of your ignore people without coming across as either extremely petty and immature, if people know why you declined, or unreliable and unavailable, if they don't know your reason.

To me, the biggest drawback is this:  Sooner or later, there's a good chance that there will be a business reason you must work with someone you prefer to avoid.  Once that happens, you will either be at odds with management by refusing (for what will likely be perceived as 'no good reason') or you'll be at a significant disadvantage trying to collaborate with someone who will possibly realize you have pointedly ignored them up to this stage.

If you don't overdo it, so the situation is more like "invest most of my energy in the people I prefer" and less "stringently avoid ever interacting with people I don't prefer"  I think it is viable, even fairly normal to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. I'm not exactly sure how you would be interacting in an IT department with so many people and so many ranks, that there are groups that are beneficial for you to hangout with and other groups that are negative to you to hang out with.

Generally...

Professionally, you should be treating all, from the employees on corrective action, to your top all stars equitably. Others around you shouldn't perceive bias or favoritism. Decisions should be made with quantifiable justification. In the workplace environment, perceptions by others, whether justified or not, can set up roadblocks or open opportunities.

Positive working relationships and figuring out what is important/motivational to others are very important within your team and across other teams. Having good morale is imperative for productivity. However, based on your initial question, I'm perceiving socializing on the clock with random people in your department vs fostering positive working relationships within and across teams. Additionally, if you're a senior manager with 2 layers of leadership between you and the 20 year olds making $13/hr manning the  phones, it is inappropriate for you to have lunch **everyday** with a group of the 20 year olds.

So, no, if you are keeping your relationships appropriate for coworkers and subordinates, no, there is not a reason you should be avoiding some and only hanging out with others. In fact, professionally, that would probably be the wrong thing to do. If there is too much or inappropriate socializing going on, then, you should probably address it yourself in a professional manner, especially if you are in some leadership capacity, whether its your team or someone else's team.

Finally, gossip, though it happens, doesn't belong in the workplace. Don't engage in it and shut it down when it happens.

This is executive maturity, and, by teaching it to others, you are helping the culture, thereby becoming part of the solution.